# How to get ungapped sequences from BLAST output?

Tags: python, biopython, fasta, blast

I am interested in getting ungapped sequences from BLAST output in FASTA format. I thought I could use `hsps_no_gap` but it's not working. Is there any method I can use to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of the BLAST output? XML? You could take the hsps from the blast output and do the following:

```
for alignment in blast_record.alignments:
    for hsp in alignment.hsps:
        query_no_gaps = hsp.query.replace("-","")
        sbjct_no_gaps = hsp.sbjct.replace("-","")
```

Then use these new variables to write to fasta.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your sequences are stored in `SeqIO.Seq` objects.

You probably want to use the `ungap` method within `SeqIO.Seq`. The [documentation](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Seq.Seq-class.html#ungap) is quite good. `ungap()` is a better choice than a string replace operation (it can infer the gap character from the sequence alphabet, for example).

Example code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

seq_records = SeqIO.parse("input.fasta", format='fasta')
for record in seq_records:
    seq_ungapped = record.seq.ungap('-')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick up sequences with no GAPS try using

```
for records in blast:
   if records.alignments:
   for align in records.alignments:
      if align.hsps.gap == 0
      print ("These ID have ungapped alignment : %s" % records.query)
```